# sending control charactors to external process in Java

Tags: java, process, ctrl

I am connecting to "/bin/bash" in ubuntu using:

```
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

Here cmd is a String with different commands that i read and write from process.
Now i have come across a situation, where i login to remote machiens using ssh and while reading writing information to ext process, for loggin out from remote machine, i have to send control character like:

`CTRL + ]` in order to logout the session gracefully and come back to my local machine. Assuming the cmd is a String type, how can i write this `CTRL` chracter to the process?

Comment: actually on xen virtual machine it is CTRL + ], but either way i am interested in CTRL

Comment: Did you try to send CTRL (17) and then ] (93)? I mean just write these integer to the input stream of the process?

Comment: @AlexR, yes thanks, it would work, i was thinking i would need some special kind of encoding before sending codes but it turned out to pretty simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Control-] in ASCII is equivalent to 035 octal.  In Java you can represent this as "\035".

```
Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream());
writer.write("\035");
writer.flush();
```

It is also equivalent to decimal value of 29 so if you can write a byte with a value of 29 then that will work as well.

```
OutputStream os = process.getOutputStream();
os.write(29);
os.flush();
```

I assume `Control-]` has to do with the remote program.  You are talking about telnet?  However writing "exit\n" will also close the remote bash.

```
Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream());
writer.write("exit\n");
writer.flush();
```

You can also, obviously, close the `OutputStream` which closes the STDIN of the remote process.

```
os.close();
```

Comment: thank you, writer.write("\035") works like a charm, however the decimal did not work. But in anycase it solved the problem. Actually i am ssh'ing a virtual machine running on top of another machine and to get back to original prompt, i need this CTR + ] as exit does not work here.